# Get angle of direction from GCExtendedGamepad.leftThumbstick

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, apple-tv, gamecontroller

How do I get the angle of direction from the left/right thumb-stick of a game controller in swift? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leftThumbstick` is a `GCControllerDirectionPad`, so it has an `xAxis` and a `yAxis`. Each of those is a `GCControllerAxisInput`, which has a `value` property of type `float`. The `value` property ranges from -1 to 1, where 0 means the stick is at the center along that axis (or in the deadzone around the center).

So you can compute the angle of the stick in radians like this:

```
let controller = GCController.controllers()[0]
let gamepad = controller.extendedGamepad!
let stick = gamepad.leftThumbstick
let radians = atan2(stick.yAxis.value, stick.xAxis.value)
```